# Remove the outer border line of CPTPiechart but need the border line between slices of pie

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot, pie-chart

```
CPTMutableLineStyle *line=[CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
line.lineColor=[CPTColor whiteColor]

CPTPieChart *pieChart = [[CPTPieChart alloc] init];
pieChart.borderLineStyle=line;
```

I know this will draw the border between the slices of the pie chart and also around the piechart. but i actually dont want to draw the outer border, just need the border between the slices. Does anyone can give the solution for this, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a supported feature right now. Please make a request on the Core Plot [issue tracker](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues) to have this feature added.